# Why isn't this array of dictionaries being copied/ assigned?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to fill a dictionary in a completion block but the dictionary is always empty when I print it. I have tried just assigning it, and also using a loop to append each element individually...Any insight is appreciated! The original dictionary (returned in the completion block is populated)

the data is an array of dictionaries.

```
var friendsList : [[String : AnyObject]] = [[:]]

fetchFriends(username: username) { (listOfFriends) in

        print("data set is:")    <-----This is working, the data set is full
        print(listOfFriends)

        //self.friendsList = listOfFriends  <---this code didn't work

        for person in listOfFriends {       <-------this code didn't work
            for (key,value) in person {
                let friend = [ key : value ]
                self.friendsList.append(friend)
            }
        }
    }
```

I changed the code inside the completion block to this (Don't see why this wouldn't work either...)

```
 for person in listOfFriends {

            print(person)   <-----this prints the correct information
            self.friendsList.append(person) <----this is working here
            print(self.friendsList) <---prints as expected

        }
    }
```

Then when I print friendsList in viewDidLoad AFTER calling this function to fill it, it just prints [[:]] to the console

Comment: Where are you printing `self.friendsList` to check the value?

Comment: Backtracking, I can see that you could be appending `friendsList` properly, so the array is good. Same could be for `friend`. So the next thing I'd think of is the Dictionary piece, which is `person`, correct? (Please be kind, it's your code, not mine.) If so, someplace I'd think there'd be a "Dictionary" piece of syntax like `person[key] = value` or maybe `friend[person.key] = person.value`. Where is that? How is your dictionary being populated?

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm printing it elsewhere - I can upload that code here as well but it's just a print statement: print(listOfFriends)

Comment: @dfd I've added some edits. does that give you what you need? When I print the value of person, it is the correct info. So i tried appending that info directly to the list...when i print the list after calling the function, it is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you find it empty in viewDidLoad is that the call fetchFriends is asynchronous, so it's completed after viewDidLoad is called.

What happens is:

- you call ferchFriends
- controller is loaded and viewDidLoad is called
- the property is still empty
- fetchFriends completes and property array is filled properly

Comment: Ah, I see...I am very new to this, so, with your answer being said, how can I get that information in view did load? After some research, I tried something like DispatchQueue.main.async { self.friendsList = listOfFriends} inside of the completion block to no avail

Comment: If you want that information to be available in viewdidLoad, you should preload fetchFriends before you open the ViewController. But probably you just need a spinner indicator to be displayed while you fetchFriends